# Methods for iteratively changing matrices in a set in R

Tags: r, class, replace, iteration

Currently I am working on an R project where I iteratively have to make a lot of small changes to the final output, which is stored in an self made Class. The calculation time of the problem becomes very large if the amount of iterations increase. Unfortunately, a more vectorized version of the code is not possible, because the future values to be changed depend on the current changes.

A small example of the problem that I encouter is given below. For the calculations using the Example_Class the calculations are significantly longer then for the instance where just a matrix is used. Are their methods available to speed up the calculations in R? Or should I look at extionsion to for example C++?

```
 Example_Class <- setClass(
"Example",

slots = c(
slot_1 = "matrix",
slot_2 = "matrix"
),

prototype=list(
slot_1 = matrix(1, ncol = 1, nrow = 7),
slot_2 = matrix(1, ncol = 4, nrow = 7)
)
)
Example <- Example_Class()

example_matrix_1 <- matrix(1, ncol = 1, nrow = 7)
example_matrix_2 <- matrix(1, ncol = 4, nrow = 7)

example_list <- list(example_matrix_1, example_matrix_2)

profile <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
example_matrix_2[3,3] <- (example_matrix_2[3,3] + 1)/2, 
example_list[[2]][3,3] <- (example_list[[2]][3,3] + 1)/2,
Example@slot_2[3,3] <- (Example@slot_2[3,3] + 1)/2,
times = 1000
)
profile
```